# Flutter web done button has container at top of keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, keyboard, flutter-web

I had an app that use flutter for web. every i focus on textfield and pressed the button 'done' at top keyboard of phone it will be close the keyboard but when i focused again on textfield , there was a white container at the top of keyboard. how to remove that container?
here some picture that i screenshot.

i really appreciate who help this issue. i know this relate issue has been found by other person. but i just need to hide this white container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I resolved it by upgrading Flutter to version 3.0.0 (using command `flutter upgrade`).

Comment: This does not solve the problem, I can still reproduce using Flutter 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

This is because the container is resized when the keyboard is opened.
You can prevent it.

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
...
```

And you can add SizedBox to the bottom of your layout so that to avoid overlapping your content

```
SizedBox(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
)
```